# objective-c array is only saving one object in it

Tags: objective-c

This is what I have

```
for (PFObject *object in objects){
    NSString *address = object[@"Address"];
    addArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:address, nil];
}

NSLog(@"OUTSIDE FOR LOOP");

for(NSString *add in addArray) {
    NSLog(@"%@", add);
}
```

The address string ends up printing out the amount of addresses inside the for loop if I use NSLog(@"%@", address); so I know that the address string is changing to the next one. But for some reason my array only shows the very last Address and won't save the first one.

Comment: yeah, you are **reassigning** the array upon each iteration, what do you expect? also, this has nothing to do with Xcode whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    addArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (PFObject *object in objects)
    {
        NSString *address = object[@"Address"];
        [addArray addObject:address];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the original array each time you loop through the first loop. Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [@[] mutableCopy];

for (PFObject *object in objects){
    [array addObject:object[@"Address"]];
}

for(NSString *add in addArray){
    NSLog(@"%@", add);
}
```